# Unable to bundle next.config.js for use in Cloud Functions Firebase (Next.js)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions

I am having this issue `Unable to bundle next.config.js for use in Cloud Functions Firebase` while doing `firebase deploy` but it is continuing to build and deployed successfully. The problem is when I enter website in production, all my images are getting 500 which says `"url" parameter is valid but upstream response is invalid.`

Here is my `next.config.js` file

```
const withBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer")({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === "true",
});

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  output: "standalone",
  experimental: {
    optimizePackageImports: ["react-icons", "react-pdf"],
  },
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "test.com",
      },
    ],
  },
  // eslint: {
  //   ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  // },
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(MOV|mp3|ts|node)x?$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            transpileOnly: true,
            experimentalWatchApi: true,
            onlyCompileBundledFiles: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer(nextConfig);
```

Comment: I think I am having a similar issue. I also have the unable to deploy message, with the reason being `The command line is too long`. Mine also deploys successfully, but then I get a 500 error in production. I think this 500 error is pretty generic, but if you check the firebase functions logs, you might see an error from the nextjs auto-generated function? This is the issue on mine - this function is timing out but I can't tell why. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77922288/nextjs-on-firebase-hosting-why-is-dynamic-route-triggering-a-cloud-function?noredirect=1#comment137391955_77922288