# Nextjs on firebase hosting - why is dynamic route triggering a cloud function?

Tags: firebase, next.js

I have a dynamic route, `/user/[userId]`, which points to a client side component, ie. `'use client'` is at the top of the `page.tsx` file. The page makes a fetch request to the database inside a `useEffect()` hook. This route works perfectly fine in development with `next dev`, but when it's deployed to firebase the route doesn't load. It sits there trying to call this auto-generated firebase function which eventually times out.

I was reading over the [nextjs firebase integration docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/nextjs#redirects_rewrites_and_headers) but I can't figure out why it's calling this function. My understanding is I'm not doing image optimization, nor redirects, rewrites, or headers.

For context, this is part of a larger issue because the firebase function is timing out and I'm not able to access the URL in production, but first I want to just figure out why it's calling this function in the first place.

**Tl;dr** I'm only using client components (`'use client'`), so why is nextjs calling its cloud function?

Other Info:

- Using nextjs App router
- next 13.4.7 (the latest supported version [according to the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/nextjs))
- nodejs 18
- react 18.2.0
- firebase tools 13.1.0 (latest version)

Comment: Client components might still run on the server. If you want your route to be statically generated, look into [`generateStaticParams()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#generating-static-params).